# transfer Erc-20 tokens from an adress without Eth and pay the gas from another adress or destination adress

Tags: erc-20, gas, transfer

as the title completely explains I want to transfer some erc-20 tokens from one account that has no eth in it to another how can I do so without need to deposit some eth to that account?
Is it possible that I pay the gas from destination account or other way?
Thank  you All

Comment: No, not possible.

Comment: When I deposit eth to that address it just transfers to another adress through a smart contract so Im allways short of gas to transfer that erc20 tokens

Comment: Well then someone else has the private key of that address. Maybe you can ask them to transfer those tokens for you.

Comment: @Decentramind See this article https://medium.com/mycrypto/operation-cryptokitty-rescue-93fd8e00e4f8, how some tokens were recovered from a wallet whose private key was compromised.

Comment: That topic was exactly what I was looking for thank you but the problem is I tried many times but couldn't duplicate their solution

Answer (score 0):

I've tried [this operation](https://feeno.peanut.trade/)
and it worked, but only for stable coins, I believe more relays services will come out or exists. So I managed to send usdc from an address that had no eth on it.